# I am unable to retrieve a request token using Twitter login library

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I was attempting to implement the Twitter login library located here: https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

I have followed a couple tutorials line by line just to see if I could get it working, but it gives me:

> *"This page isn’t working. MyWebsite.com is unable to handle this request."*

After looking through the code and trying some things, I realized the line that is causing it is this one in this picture:

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'autoload.php';
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'BlaBlaBlaBla'); // add your app consumer key between single quotes
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'BlaBlaBlaBla'); // add your app consumer secret key
between single quotes
define('oAUTH_CALLBACK', 'BlaBlaBlaBla/twitter/callback.php'); // your app callback URL

if (lisset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    $request_token : $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => oAUTH_CALLBACK));
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'] : $request_token['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
    $url : $connection->url('oauth/authorize', array('oauth_token' => $request_token['oauth_token']));
    echo $url;
} else {
    $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token[
    oauth_token_secret']);
    $user : $connection->get("account/verify_credentials")fl
    echo $user->screen_name;
}
?>
```

Code image:

[image]

If anyone has any experience with this and could help, it would be really helpful.

Comment: Please add relevant code as part of the question and not as a screenshot.

Comment: Just edited the code into the question. Note that I'm not familiar with PHP, so if there's anything I missed syntactically in the code compared to the picture, please edit it. As a note to OP, this is how the code __should__ be included in any question/answer post.

Comment: OP here, will do this next time, it was my first time posting. In case anyone else ever has this problem with the Twitter sign in, it could be because you did not install Curl for PHP. Thats how I solved my problem